# Verify the identity: $\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\sin^3(x)} = \frac{\csc(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I prove
$$\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\sin^3(x)} = \frac{\csc(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$

I got up to multiplying the LHS by the conjugate of the denominator and so far have:
\begin{align*}
&= \left(\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\sin^3(x)}\right)\left(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)\\  
&= \frac{\cos(x)-\cos^2(x)+1-\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)(1-\cos(x))}\\ 
&= \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin^3(x)(1-\cos(x))}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))} 
\end{align*}
I don't know where to go from here

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/)

Comment: @Surb Thanks for the help on clarifying my post

Comment: $\frac{1}{sin(x)}=cosec(x)$

Comment: Easier: $$\frac{A}{B} = \frac{C}{D} \iff AD = BC ~: ~0 \neq B,D.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is Prove that $\frac{\cos(x)+1}{(\sin^{3}(x))}=\frac{\csc(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$. Now I will prove R.H.S. from L.H.S. Therefore, we can write $\sin^{3}(x)=(\sin^{2}(x))(\sin(x))$=$(1-\cos^{2}(x))(\sin(x))$. Therefore, we can write the L.H.S. as $\frac{1}{(1+\cos(x))(\sin(x))}=\frac{\csc(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$=R.H.S.

Comment: The signs should be negative in the last equation.

Answer (score 2):

**Big Hint**

Your equality is equivalent than showing $$(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x))=\sin^2(x)$$ which is obvious using the fact that $$(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2\quad \text{and}\quad \cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\because(\cos x+1)(1-\cos x) & =1-\cos ^2 x=\sin ^2 x  =\sin ^3 x \csc x \\
\therefore \quad \frac{\cos x+1}{\sin ^3 x} & =\frac{\csc x}{1-\cos x}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially three ways to prove identities.

The first one consists in operating the LHS until reaching the RHS through allowable operations.

The second one consists in proving the difference equals zero.

And the third one consists in proving the LHS and RHS are identical to a third expression.

Let us handle the proposed exercise according to the second procedure:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos(x) + 1}{\sin^{3}(x)} - \frac{\csc(x)}{1 - \cos(x)} & = \frac{(1 + \cos(x))(1 - \cos(x)) - \sin^{3}(x)\csc(x)}{\sin^{3}(x)(1 - \cos(x))}\\\\
& = \frac{1 - \cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)}{\sin^{3}(x)(1 - \cos(x))}\\\\
& = \frac{\sin^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)}{\sin^{3}(x)(1 - \cos(x))} = 0
\end{align*}
Notice as well the proposed identity holds true in the following set:
\begin{align*}
S = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid (x\neq k\pi)\wedge(k\in\mathbb{Z})\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!